# Jquery UI Date Picker... only allow Fridays?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to only allow users to select Fridays. Basically they are choosing the start date for a schedule, and the schedules always must start on a Friday.

I am not really concerned with whether the other days are displayed or not as long as if they are displayed, then they are disabled.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the [`beforeShowDate` option](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-beforeShowDay), like this:

```
​$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        return [date.getDay() == 5];
    }
})​​​​​;​
```

[You can try a demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/nWAnz/140/), we're just checking if the [`.getDay()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getday.asp) on the date it's trying to show is `5` (Friday), and if so `true` is the first element in the array, `false` otherwise, which disables the date in the picker.